# Mailto returning UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: java, android, html

I'm working in an app in android. I need to add a page with legal info, which is done in a html file.

So, inside this file I have a mail that I will like to open the mail app when clicked. Here is how it's been added:

```
<a href="mailto:mailname@example.com" target="_blank">mailname@example.com</a>
```

But, when being clicked, it's giving me an error: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.
What am I doing wrong?

I'm using a minSDK = 16 with Android Studio 3.0.

To load the html files into my app I'm doing this:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/info.html");
```